# IE11 crashes when printing without Print dialog

Tags: internet-explorer

IE11 crashes during unprompted printing (without print dialog) when running in IE10 compatibility mode.

This is the sample HTML code that causes IE11 to crash:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" />
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <title>Microsoft Internet Explorer print test</title>

        <script language="VBScript">
            sub Print()
                OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
                OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
                OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
                call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
            End Sub
            document.write "<object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        Print test.
        <a href="#" onclick="Print()">Print</a>     
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error reported in the Event Log:

```
Faulting application name: IEXPLORE.EXE, version: 11.0.9600.17840, time stamp: 0x555fe1bb
Faulting module name: shlwapi.DLL, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b9e2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001bb3a
Faulting process id: 0x2434
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0a69151fbbc71
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\shlwapi.DLL
Report Id: 92c64479-1284-11e5-b1ca-005056c00008
```

This started happening after kb3021952 was installed. Uninstalling kb3021952 doesn't fix the problem.

Is there any known workaround for this problem? What are the other options for unprompted printing in IE? Is maybe there an undocumented command line parameter available for this purpose (an equivalent to '--kiosk-printing' in Chrome)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix was released by Microsoft: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/MS15-106 and described in https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3099587.